# What happens now to reputation points when questions are moved between 'stacks'?

Tags: discussion, reputation, migration, reputation-recalc

After the 'great recalc', do migrated questions *and answers, and comments, and flags, and votes et al* now count for reputation points on the destination site? This wasn't made completely clear in the blog post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they do.

Actually, they always did, except there hadn't been a recalc like this since 2008.
(this also works for badges, but that did work before the recalc, I got awarded a few when some old pre-meta post of mine got migrated here)

Keep in mind that you also lose the *source* reputation for answers on migrated questions, as they are soft deleted when migrated.