# Views count on migrated questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration, views

I followed a link for a question that was on Stack Overflow (which interested me) which got migrated to Server Fault and the "Views" of the question was at 2 on Server Fault... The question had received multiple comments which should indicate that it had been viewed by quite a few more than 2. Is the view count is "reset" once the question has been moved?

The count has since changed to a couple more and there has been further comments so I assume this isn't a caching issue...

[Question for whatever reason](https://serverfault.com/questions/142545/who-are-good-suppliers-of-net-4-hosted-virtual-private-servers-may-2010/142546#142546).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It is correct for a question to reset at 0 views on the target site at the time of migration. That's how many views it has there when migrated. Views on the source site isn't relevant at migration time.
2. Views are buffered and written in intervals. Even though these buffer settings are per-site , it still takes time to hit the buffer intervals, particularly on SU and SF.

Comment: thanks Jeff for clarifying...best to ask when things don't look as you might expect, but the explanation is completely sound with me!

Answer (score 0):

The number of views is the sum of [the views shown here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847909/who-are-good-suppliers-of-net-4-hosted-virtual-private-servers-may-2010) (now 17) plus [the views shown here at SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/142545/who-are-good-suppliers-of-net-4-hosted-virtual-private-servers-may-2010/142546#142546) (now 19).

This is opposite to the behaviour of votes, where the votes count only where the question was moved.  See [What happens now to rep points when questions are moved between ‘stacks’?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43967/what-happens-now-to-rep-points-when-questions-are-moved-between-stacks)