# How does Stack Overflow implement its view counter?

Tags: discussion, views

In comments [to this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58369/did-anyone-notice-that-tech-efreedom-com-seem-to-be-scraping-republishing-sos-po/58374#58374), Jeff Atwood remarks:

> [O]ur view counts are very very strict
>   -- more akin to visits as they are unique per IP per 15 minute interval

What else, besides a request from a given IP in a given 15 minute interval, goes into adding a "view" to a Stack Overflow question?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70187/what-is-the-benefit-of-denormalizing-page-views/70194#70194 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50147/views-count-on-migrated-questions/50152#50152

Comment: @random: post as a answer, I'll upvote.