# Question views should be migrated along with upvotes

Tags: feature-request, migration, migrated-questions

I just saw [a question migrated from MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251565/add-optional-box-for-spam-flags-letting-you-say-why-you-think-its-spam) and it immediately made me think about [my confusion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251286/questions-that-have-more-upvotes-than-views) long time ago. The reason was, of course, the fact that the number of views **doesn't get migrated and always resets to 1 after migration**.

For example, the question I just mentioned now has 218 upvoted and 21 views. This huge number of upvotes this question received while being on MSO. Fine. But the views didn't get migrated - [it had 1127 views](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288127/add-optional-box-for-spam-flags-letting-you-say-why-you-think-its-spam?noredirect=1). Those current 21 views is since the question was migrated, which is not right. I propose to migrate the number of views.

<sub>There is another problem. Favorites aren't migrated also. But I don't think it should be "fixed" because actually not every user who favorite's question before the migration has an account on the target site.</sub>

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50147/views-count-on-migrated-questions

Comment: @rand yep and my is the direct request :)

Comment: Which means those views happened on the destination site out of thin air?

Comment: @rand yes, and I don't think it should work this way.

Comment: @random better than skewing the vote/view ratio

Comment: the issue is still present on  2021-01-13